# Get Apple Id of the user after InApp purchase

Tags: ios, ios6, in-app-purchase

I have implemented **In-App purchase** successfully in my app. Now what I want is the **apple Id** of the user so as to send a thank you message to him. Is it possible to be done.?

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: It's also a really, really bad idea.

Comment: I understood the answer throug this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009530/is-it-possible-to-get-the-users-apple-id-through-the-sdk where it is explained in depth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just cannot. There's no publicly available API for retrieving such piece of information.

(Thank God I'd say)

Comment: Does apple state it in any of its documentation anywhere.? I wanted to go through.

Comment: It's the other way around: Apple won't state everything you can't do with the APIs. It just doesn't say that you can.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible and it's certainly not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Nope That is not possible but what you can do it is via application ,Show a thank you screen when it is successful ,or any way you have his mail collected as registration then send a mail to that