# user's AppleId programmatically in iphone

Tags: ios, apple-id

is this possible to get the user's apple id which is currently login to device? Actually I implemented inapp purchases and I get a device id and Apple id of the user when it purchase the app.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not possible.
Instead of AppleId, you  can use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]`.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. It's a privacy element like the UDID.

You can read more about this here : [Privacy issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2106855/1884877)

But, if you want, you can use the [identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) provided by Apple using this method :

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. You can only retrieve the device's UDID. it's a privacy issue, just like their phone number. But you can get the certificate (Acknowledgement) for every purchase from apple server for a particular user.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't get Apple Id. Instead of that you could use identifierForVendor.

**Objective-c:**

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]
```

**Swift 3+:**

```
UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
```

If you want to read more about collecting user data check this out [Apple Policy!](https://www.apple.com/in/legal/privacy/en-ww/)

or you can use this (Swift 3):

`UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString`

For older versions:

`UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor`

or if you want a string:

`UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about apple id but you can grab device id programmatically. If you using hybrid app, you can using push phonegap plugin.

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/08/29/implement-push-notifications-for-android-and-ios-phonegap-part-2/

For native

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

BTW, device id and UDID is a different thing.

Comment: I have to retrive the apple id not the  device id . by which user is currently login.?

Comment: device id you can get it from user, if apple id i think cant. I never heard about it.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't get that information. The only thing you can get are information from UIDevice (look it up on the apple doc) or a "fake UDID" (unique key that isn't the UDID) using `[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]`, and the IP.

So you can identify your users in a unique way, but not get their information.

I really suggest you go browse the doc about the UIDevice, maybe you'll find something that you need there too

Answer (score 0):

ou can use this (Swift 3):

UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
For older versions:

UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor
or if you want a string:

UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString